# VBA code for comparing first column of multiple spreadsheet with mastersheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code for comparing first column and highlight the cell in first column of sheet2 which is not there in sheet1.

I am new to VBA and not good in coding part and need this to work in a excel sheet which has multiple spreadsheet(This may vary from 5 to 10).
sheet1 is the master sheet and other sheet should be compared with the master sheet and highlight the cell which is not present in master sheet.

```
    Public Sub CompareSheets()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range, rng As Range

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng = ws1.Range("A1:A20")
    For Each cell In rng
        Celladdress = cell.Address
        If cell <> ws2.Range(Celladdress) Then
           cell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
           ws2.Range(Celladdress).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
     Next cell    
   End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be a 'row-by-row' comparison or can a value in sheet2's column A be anywhere in sheet1's column A?

Comment: It can be any where in the sheet. just i want to compare cells of sheet2 with sheet 1 and highlight if it is not present in sheet1. I want the code modification which can apply for multiple spreadsheet(ex: Sheet1, sheet2,sheet3....sheetN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code avoids a row-by-row comparison (per your comments) and looks for each value in column A of Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, etc to be found somewhere in column A of Sheet1. It also locates rows that are greater than the total number of rows with values in Sheet1.

This does not force the cells to vbYellow. Instead, it uses conditional formatting to show vbYellow on non-matching cells. These can be filtered for just as forced vbYellow cells can. The benefit here is that once a value has been corrected (a match to Sheet1!A:A is made), the highlight will be auto-magically removed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CompareSheets()
    Dim lrw1 As Long, lrwn As Long, w As Long

    'get the last row of values in master sheet
    With Worksheets(1)
        lrw1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With


    'the first worksheet (e.g. worksheets(1) ) is the 'master sheet' so we start at 2
    For w = 2 To Worksheets.Count
        With Worksheets(w)
            lrwn = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(Application.Max(lrwn, lrwn), "A"))
                .FormatConditions.Delete
                With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
                        Formula1:="=OR(ROW()>" & lrw1 & ", ISNA(MATCH($A1, " & Worksheets(1).Columns("A").Address(external:=True) & ", 0)))")
                    With .Interior
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .Color = vbYellow
                    End With
                    .StopIfTrue = True
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next w

End Sub
```

FWIW, I found your narrative a bit confusing. It either contradicted the supplied code or contradicted itself. The logic behind this proposed solution comes largely from your comments.

Comment: Thanks it worked, only issue i am facing is may be i am not able to explain the things in better way i am new in coding,
Sheet1 column A "Master sheet" has 100 cell and other spreadsheet have around 153 cells and this code is work perfect till 100th row. After 100th row it is highlighting all the cells in sheet 2. In actual situation sheet2 ..sheet N may have more cell or less cells then sheet 1

Comment: That is actually what it is designed to do. Go to the worksheet and look at Home, Styles, Conditional Formatting. You should be able to adjust the formula by removing the part that states TRUE if the row number exceeds the max row number from the master sheet. Adjust the code to suit and you will be set.